# play1.3.1 websocket address is 404 error

Tags: java, playframework

I used play1.3.1's websocket under tomcat8, and the connection address was 404 error， play's websocket didn't support Tomcat？ Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a libraries issue, clean and then deploy your project it'll run fine..

Also check if this is the root of your error:

Tomcat has a JSR-356 (i.e. the websocket API) implementation since version 7.0.47. Which also provides the javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar library. You might need it at compile time but the server will provide it at runtime

Make sure javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar does not get deployed in your WAR, do a right click in your Eclipse server view, Clean... followed by Clean Tomcat work directory... then a Publish and try again.

Hopefully this will be helpful